# Query blog roll of recent post by category from a website to another

Tags: wordpress

Can you help me on this one?

> **The client wants the articles on the main blog site to be queried in a
>   sidebar of a landing page.**

Is it possible? How?

Any answer is appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

```
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load('feed/url/goes/here');
$feed = array();
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    $item = array ( 
        'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'category' => $node->getElementsByTagName('category')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        );
    array_push($feed, $item);
}
$limit = 5;

    for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
        $cat = $feed[$x]['category'];
        $cat_name = get_the_title();

            if ($cat = $cat_name){
            $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
            $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
            $date = date('m / d / Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
            echo '<p><strong><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'" class="boldandred">'.$date.'</a></strong><br />';
            echo '<p class="smallbutreadable">'.$description.'</p>';

            }else{
                echo '';
            }
    }
```

I can retrieve the feed items, but not in a category. It must be in a **category**.

Comment: What you can do if that´s what he wants is to create a custom feed of those article posts in your main blog. That´s something you can search and find many tutorials on how to do. Then on the landing page is just to load and display that feed info, let´s say you create a feed with title, thumnail, link, description, then in your landing page you can put that too. You will need for this last step know how to read xml files, let´s say using php and some scripts.

Comment: now i´m seeging your code updated. I suggest to do all the thing on the feed itslef, not on the landing page, on landing page just serve the xml feed as it is, don´t try to load the entire feed site with all the post asgined to many categories, do that on the feed, on site side. So re-code your feed to show only that particular category and only 5 items.